# Next.js server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, getserversideprops

I need help regarding next.js SSR. I'm new to next.js and building an e-commerce store. where i want to fetch navigation menu on server side so its available as soon as page load. don't want to fetch on client side. one way is to fetch navigation on each page using getStaticProps and pass as a prop to component. but I don't want to use this approach. instead I want to fetch it once and share between multiple pages.

I'll appreciate your responses
Thank You.

I tried using getStaticProps on every page

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please note that Stack Overflow is not made to ask for tutorial, video or book/technologie recommendation. Please use Stack Overflow to get help with code and see [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping the app in a "Layout" component?

This is a common approach.

So you would have the _app.js file wrapped by a wrapper component.

And that wrapper component has the getStaticProps.

Comment: I think getStaticProps can only be used in pages not in individual components